# Set chinese in xkb

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout, xkb

I tried the command
`setxkbmap cn` but nothing happened.

I'd like to write characters in pinyin, so that it would automatically write
chinese characters and then have the possibility to turn in back to english
with
`setxkbmap us`

I'd like to do it from command line, because I'm using `i3` window manager.

Comment: Setxkbmap is not sufficient, do you have the appropriate [input method](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/2-best-chinese-pinyin-im-ubuntu-16-04/) installed? That's how Chinese/Japanese input normally works. [Additional link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59356/how-do-i-get-chinese-input-to-work).

Comment: @undercatapplaudsMonica Can I set everything from the commandline? (I'm using i3 window manager)

Comment: @undercatapplaudsMonica Yet important for me is to be able to set it back to english. :-)

Comment: I have no experience with i3, but looking up "i3 fcitx" and "i3 ibus" gives a fair number of guides on how to set it up.

Comment: Unless your [keyboard looks like this](https://i.imgur.com/159JdT2.jpg) you need the input method as suggested by @undercatapplaudsMonica

Comment: @undercatapplaudsMonica Please write it as an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: @xralf Done, although my answer is fairly barebones. I strongly encourage you to also write an answer once you set everything up, too, and share your first-hand experience with others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you will need an [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method)(Input Method Editor) to enter languages that make use of Chinese characters (e.g. Mandarin, Japanese, etc.).

Some of the more popular IMEs (in no particular order) include [Fcitx](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Fcitx), [IBus](https://github.com/ibus/ibus) and [SouGou PinYin](https://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/?r=pinyin).

Installing an IME is generally straightforward on the mainstream distros, you just install the package from the official repo or link with the distro's package manager. [This link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/2-best-chinese-pinyin-im-ubuntu-16-04/), for example, describes this in detail for two input methods.

After installing an IME, you should be able to switch between English and Pinyin with the IME-specific shortcut, typically it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default.